# How do I iterate over a pixel array from a specific location to find a vertical/horizontal line of pixels?

Tags: c#, arrays, pixel

[image]

Hello I am trying to create a line from a list of points I will find by traversing an array of pixels.  It's basically a box in an image but I know the center point of the box.  So I want to loop through the image diagonally and see if the pixels change from 0 to 1 so I know that's part of the box.  I want to find the right vertical side of the box first but then change the algorithm to also find it's bottom.

I know how to normally traverse an image but can't figure out how to modify it for my purpose:

```
        var horizontalLinePoints = new List<Point>();
        var verticalLinePoints = new List<Point>();
        for (int x = centralPoint.X; x < originalImageWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = centralPoint.Y; y < originalImageHeight; y++)
            {
                int index = originalImageWidth * x + y;
                if (newImagePixelArray[index] == 1)
                {
                   horizontalLinePoints.Add(new Point(x, y)); 
                }
            }
        }
```

newImagePixelArray is a one-dimensional byte array.

EDIT:

To further explain I want to determine the angle of the box to see if it's tilted.  Some of the suggestions list finding the first pixel to the right then traversing that pixel vertically to determine the each point along that line.  I believe the code to at least move right finding the first pixel is this:

```
// List to store locations of vertical lines pixels
        var verticalLinePoints = new List<Point>();
        // Loop horizontally
        for (int x = centralPoint.X; x < originalImageWidth; x++)
        {
            int index = originalImageWidth * x + centralPoint.Y;

            // Find the first 'vertical' pixel
            if (newImagePixelArray[index] == 1)
            {
                verticalLinePoints.Add(new Point(x, centralPoint.Y));
                break;
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2:

@TaW has an appropriate algorithm to accomplish this, I was however able to create the logic to find my line:

```
var verticalLinePoints = new List<Point>();
        var horizontalLinePoints = new List<Point>();
       for (int x = 0; x < originalImageWidth; x++)
       {
           for (int y = centralPoint.Y; y < originalImageHeight; y++)
           {
               int index = originalImageWidth * x + y;
               if (newImagePixelArray[index] >= 1)
               {
                   verticalLinePoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: Please define the phrase "loop though the image diagonally". Did you mean "walk through the image diagonally"?

Comment: Maybe he means run through the image diagonally

Comment: Are you sure this line works? int index = originalImageWidth * x + y;

Comment: If you know you are starting from the center point of the box, and that the box is not tilted, then you cannot do a diagonal search for the right side "first" unless you also know that the box is taller than it is wide. Why not just search horizontally to the right side, then follow it down to the bottom? If you know there is only one shape present then you could use something like a binary search to find the bottom after finding the side.

Comment: Dir @Habo's comment help you to solve your problem? Also: Is the array 1-dimensional? What do you want to do with the list of Points?? Do you really need just the right on bottom lines???

Comment: @MarkLakata - Yes I mean walk through the image diagonally or iterate through the pixels in a way that allows me to find the vertical pixels of my box.  walking or running ;-)

Comment: @Dennis_E That index should work but I don't know if it needs to change if the for loop changes for diagonal traversing.  More info on that index: http://www.processing.org/tutorials/pixels/

Comment: @TaW The pixels are stored in a 1-dimensional array. When I get a list of the vertical and horizontal points I want to draw and or create a line then determine the angle of it. I would need at least 2 lines to determine the angle.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't qute understand. Finding the right (or bottom) border is trivial, when you have the centerpoint: iterate horizontally right (or vertically down) till you hit it. Doing the same to the left and up gets you the box defined completely. Your other requirements, I don't get.. Please try to edit your question to explain the result better..

Comment: @HABO The example is a best case scenario, there will be other scenarios where the box will be tilted.  Essentially I want to determine the angle of the box.  As for searching horizontally to the right side do you know how that would for loop would look?  I mocked something up that I think will find the first pixel to the right but then how do I "follow it down to the bottom"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited question now makes sense. Still the best way is to go straight, say, to the right until you hit a point on the right border, let's call it **R**.

Then repeat straight up and down from the center point until you have one point on the upper and lower border, say **T** and **B**.

Next you follow the y-coordinate of point **R** both up and down, until they leave the border. The points where they do shall be called **R0** and **R3**; the last points before they do shall be called **R1** and **R2**.

If **R1** and **R2** have the same y-coodinates as **T** and **B** your box is not tilted. To get the angle you can measure it from the line through **R0** and **R3**.

To get the most precise angle you would have to repeat the procedure for a horizontal line and then use the longer distance.

Comment: @Invizion: The original answer was wrong about how to measure the angle. See the edited answer!

Comment: This sounds interesting. What if there are missing pixels in the line? (perhaps from captured images or corruption). What if the resolution is too low to capture sharp lines, so the line jumps +1 pixels each Y-axis (or X-axis) increase? So, for a 45* angle line it might be made of points: (0,0) (1,2), (2,4), (3,6) etc..

Comment: Yes, in many real world mages you will have to allow for these complications. One will have to modify code to make sure it will work. One way might be to increase contrast to avoid grey pixels, another to repeat the search processes a few times a ixel or two apart to get, say, three results and pick the best fits. Since the question talks about getting black and white pixels only I left these considerations out of the answer. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+contrast+gamma) post about image corrections..